# How do I add, say, n entries of x to a list in one shot?

Tags: python, list

For instance, say list `L = [0,1,2,3]` and I want to add 10 elements of 4:

```
L=[0,1,2,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4]
```

without needing to use a loop or anything

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is pretty simple thanks to the fact you can add and/or multiply lists:

```
L += [4] * 10
```

Here is the proof:

```
>>> L = [0,1,2,3]
>>> L += [4] * 10
>>> L
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4]
```

Comment: @user1123950, if you're going to use this code for something else than just ints or floats (say lists, dicts, or your own classes), there is something **very important** that you have to know: the `*` operator wil create a list of the **same object** repeated n times, so if you do `L += [MyClass()] * 10` all those elements would reference the same object, so if you modify one of them, you will be modifying all of them.

Answer (score 2):

```
L.extend([4] * 10)

L.extend([some_mutable_object for x in range(10)])
```

Comment: The second line doesn't work for `some_mutable_object`, only for `some_expression_that_returns_or_creates_a_mutable_object()`. Otherwise you still just get 10 references to the same object.

Comment: Sorry for the revisionist conversation. I accidentally posted that comment before I meant to, so I went back and finished it, but by then you'd already responded to the initial version.